# Hibernate and use of criteria method setFirstResult

Tags: sql, hibernate, criteria

I'm trying to learn the hibernate criteria API but I'm puzzled by the criteria method setFirstResult.
I don't understand why I would want to use it except in the rarest of circumstances.   It seems to me that when I retrieve information from a database, I'm only interested in establishing some criteria and then executing the query against the criteria.   Why do I care from which index number in the database the results should be read.  It is not something I normally do when I write sql queries yet I see this method all over the hibernate literature.  Is this method something I always have to invoke when writing Hibernate queries or can I safely ignore it?

Thank you,

Elliott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is typically used when displaying paginated results of a query. The first page goes from 0 to 19, the second page from 20 to 39, etc.

Comment: OK.  For the class of applications that I deal with, I don't have to do pagination.    So it looks like I can ignore it but I'll keep it in mind if I ever need to do this.  Thanks.

Comment: @Elliott What is the SQL equivalent of setFirstResult ?

Answer (score 0):

Well I use it in a bunch of places.. its unfortunate or outright lucky/dumb that you have run into a case where you needed to page your results in which case you generally right queries that pick from one index to another. consider the case where you want to display the audit log of an app that is stored for every write action on the page. in that case you will show the 20 results based on which page the user is and what field the audit log is sorted on.